# make: No rule to make target 'external/intel-boot-tools/boot.mk'

Tags: android, makefile, target, rule

I'm trying to make an Android ROM for my Razr I phone (x86-atom). Everything works,
but when I run `make` it shows this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'external/intel-boot-tools/boot.mk'.
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] before too long. Does the error message include the spaces around the slashes? If so, that may be the whole problem; you probably need to get rid of the spaces in the path name. If you don't have spaces around the slashes, then it appears that your `makefile` needs to find a file `external/intel-boot-tools/boot.mk` under the current directory, and it is failing to find it. Since we can't see your `makefile`, it is difficult to be more precise than that.  Do you have all the SDK you need?  Have you set all the environment you need?

Comment: I have the sdk, and i have all what i need. I don't have spaces arround the slashes and the folder intel-boot-tools dont exist.

Makefile:
### DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE ###
include build/core/main.mk
### DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE ###

Build/core/main.mk file:
[link](http://pastebin.com/w4k5uZcb)

Comment: You'll probably need to show (a cut down version of) your makefile. Please learn what an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) is and remove as much of the makefile as possible while retaining the error.  You can either copy the file to `xyz.mk` and then run `make -f xyz.mk` or you can rely on your version control system to recover the `makefile` after you've hacked it mercilessly.  Is there a line that says `include external/intel-boot-tools/boot.mk` (possibly using a macro for the file name)?

Comment: i searched and i can't find a line that says include external/intel-boot-tools/boot.mk, and i don't find a macro. But i find this in my device devtree (device/motorola/smi/boardconfig.mk):
BOARD_CUSTOM_BOOTIMG_MK := external/intel-boot-tools/boot.mk

Comment: So you'll probably need to find the makefile entries that reference `BOARD_CUSTOM_BOOTIMG_MK`, or macros defined in terms of it and references to those macros, repeated indefinitely.

Comment: Found all of this http://pastebin.com/CpcJeV1v

Comment: Since you said you found BOARD_CUSTOM_BOOTIMG_MK defined and the makefile contains `
ifdef BOARD_CUSTOM_BOOTIMG_MK /
include $(BOARD_CUSTOM_BOOTIMG_MK) /
endif` (slashes for line endings), it is expecting to find the file to `include` it, but it is not finding the file.  Either you need to provide the file or you need to undefine BOARD_CUSTOM_BOOTIMG_MK.

Comment: Solved, the intel-boot-tools was not downloaded, I found the folder and moved it to where it should be. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Link to this instead in your boardconfig.mk and add it to your manifest so it syncs automatically. https://github.com/turl/razr-i-boot-tools

It looks like your boardconfig was referencing a dir you never synced. Razr-i-boot-tools is more specific to your device (obviously), so I would just use that.